# HTML + CSS table layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong but I can't seem to figure out a simple layout.  I basically want a header than spans 100% width and have a fixed height (say 120px).  I then need a left menu and the content on the right.  If the viewport changes, I need to show scrollbars if the content is greater than the viewport (overflow: auto).  BUT, I can't seem to make it work properly.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Client Layout Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
        body 
        { 
          margin: 0; 
          padding: 0; 
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%; 
        } 
        #container 
        { 
          position: fixed; 
          height: 100%; 
          width: 100%; 
          background: #eaeaea; 
        } 
        #header 
        { 
          background: #000000; 
          height: 120px;
        } 

        .PageTitle{
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }

        .leftMenu{
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="header"> 
        <div class="PageTitle">CLIENT NAME AND LOGO GO HERE!</div>
    </div> 
      <div id="container" style="overflow: auto;"> 
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%;"> 
          <tr valign="top"> 
             <td style="background: #5a7394; width: 235px;"> 
                    <div class="leftMenu">
                        List of links goes here
                    </div>            
             </td> 
             <td style="background: #ffffff; padding-left: 10px;"> 
                <div style="text-align: justify;">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse condimentum egestas nulla nec accumsan. Suspendisse pretium luctus rhoncus. Suspendisse euismod, magna non tempor lobortis, sapien velit ornare est, a venenatis enim erat a lectus. Nunc placerat, lorem ac viverra aliquet, nisl nunc varius sem, nec commodo dui mauris interdum augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras vulputate nunc non lorem mattis luctus. Sed sit amet lorem venenatis ipsum blandit commodo. Mauris tempor dolor a nisl tristique volutpat. Aliquam tincidunt rhoncus diam vitae faucibus. Sed consequat diam in eros laoreet placerat.</p>
                    <p>Pellentesque consectetur tincidunt tortor, a laoreet massa interdum vitae. Nam faucibus ante sit amet lacus pulvinar eleifend. Sed iaculis tempor nunc ut tincidunt. Phasellus id metus ac purus fringilla pellentesque pulvinar nec arcu. In augue lacus, imperdiet et egestas vel, laoreet eget lorem. Donec ante tellus, feugiat eu feugiat sed, consequat sed felis. Duis porta est sit amet erat lacinia vehicula. Nullam congue luctus sapien, ut suscipit augue varius a. In consectetur dignissim urna. Donec adipiscing ornare magna eget laoreet. Fusce purus mauris, vestibulum id feugiat ac, pretium at libero. Nam placerat, ante ornare gravida cursus, magna risus eleifend dolor, ut auctor velit purus at ligula. Nullam ultrices, orci fermentum semper euismod, velit metus condimentum lacus, consequat interdum dolor orci ut elit.</p>
                    <p>Aliquam quis nibh ac ipsum dignissim sodales ac id arcu. Ut rutrum dolor at mauris ullamcorper dignissim. Vivamus sagittis iaculis varius. Nullam pharetra enim id lectus placerat venenatis. Ut gravida nisl magna. Praesent pretium viverra convallis. Nullam molestie, est vitae luctus rhoncus, ante mi porttitor dolor, id fermentum sem eros et dui. Quisque imperdiet, justo nec aliquet dictum, lorem felis pulvinar augue, at facilisis magna metus a elit. Fusce molestie nunc nec dui blandit nec cursus neque molestie. Sed tempus metus et neque malesuada ut lacinia tortor suscipit. Sed tristique sagittis elit, tempor tincidunt augue tempus at. Vestibulum convallis volutpat euismod.</p>
                    <p>Integer mattis vulputate viverra. Cras ultrices, lectus vitae mollis pharetra, dui odio porttitor quam, vel iaculis arcu felis vel arcu. Nam posuere viverra erat, nec molestie nunc egestas a. Proin pharetra, velit quis pretium ullamcorper, arcu dui condimentum sem, eget vulputate urna turpis vitae lorem. Suspendisse vitae felis sit amet odio dapibus vulputate. Nam hendrerit tempor neque, ac dapibus turpis ullamcorper eget. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed ipsum justo, venenatis in dignissim sit amet, consectetur gravida elit. Praesent tincidunt, orci vel elementum condimentum, nisl purus auctor orci, in ullamcorper nulla nisl et mi. Suspendisse volutpat urna vel nunc dapibus venenatis consequat nibh blandit. Cras id ipsum orci. Pellentesque eget odio dui. Fusce porta erat quis eros ornare varius. In viverra dui nec est rhoncus sed tincidunt augue imperdiet. Etiam a lectus et dui mollis fringilla.</p>
                    <p>Sed odio sapien, viverra in egestas eu, tempor consequat erat. Vestibulum laoreet felis eu ante dapibus porttitor malesuada quam varius. Morbi egestas quam nec metus ultrices ultricies. Sed lacus libero, mattis ut feugiat at, iaculis a orci. Fusce ullamcorper accumsan dui. Aenean sit amet condimentum velit. Suspendisse turpis magna, ornare in sodales vitae, lacinia id elit. Sed non nulla ac augue egestas lacinia et a arcu. Aenean vel dolor lectus, eu imperdiet sem. Integer vel tellus sed dolor mattis condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus eget massa massa, imperdiet volutpat velit. Duis a massa sit amet ligula scelerisque venenatis semper at ipsum. Aenean varius nisi a diam pretium ac facilisis metus aliquet. Ut tempus ante ac leo cursus in convallis nibh malesuada. Praesent sit amet eros neque, luctus fringilla nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam est erat, volutpat eget vulputate eget, gravida ut lorem. Nam ultricies nibh nec turpis vulputate lacinia eget vel eros. Nullam nulla tellus, porttitor id tempor non, rhoncus vitae neque.</p>
                </div>
             </td> 
          </tr> 
        </table> 
      </div> 
</body>
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Incorrect Layout]

Here's the issues and what I need it to do:
[image: Would Like to Look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsbin to help you get started:

http://jsbin.com/exevi3/edit

Hope this helps. Notice that the example is using css for layout instead of tables. That is the recommended best practice these days.

Bob

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setHeight();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    setHeight();
  });

  function setHeight(){
    var headHeight = $("#header").height();
    var docHeight = $(window).height();
    var h = docHeight - headHeight - 50;
    $("#menu").css('height', h + 'px');
    $("#content").css('height', h + 'px');    
  }
});
```

The '50' in there is because there is some additional padding not being accounted for. Could be that I should be using innerHeight().

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rutrum aliquam diam, et facilisis lectus auctor vel. Praesent sit amet ante sem, id commodo leo. Praesent eget nisl leo. Quisque vel lectus metus. Morbi pellentesque scelerisque ipsum, eget fermentum sapien molestie et. Vestibulum quis elementum augue. Donec consectetur elit id ligula imperdiet a euismod mi pharetra. Nulla nec sapien et lectus porta sodales. Aliquam sed egestas justo. Integer adipiscing, felis non vehicula commodo, leo tellus aliquam nulla, et cursus nibh felis ac risus. Duis sit amet tempor lectus.</p>

      <p>Ut mauris tellus, auctor ut mollis vitae, malesuada at nunc. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper viverra. Etiam elementum erat eget nulla bibendum a faucibus purus feugiat. Nam enim eros, placerat vitae volutpat tincidunt, tristique ac lectus. Proin elit risus, eleifend non varius eget, pretium non lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla blandit lacus blandit nisl porttitor eleifend. Sed adipiscing, leo nec pellentesque tempus, tellus velit pulvinar turpis, euismod pulvinar est odio et elit. Etiam quis turpis a tortor condimentum convallis eu nec velit. Nullam volutpat luctus nisi, in sollicitudin lectus adipiscing vitae. Pellentesque eu neque ut nisl iaculis lacinia nec non odio. Ut id nibh nec leo vulputate malesuada at sit amet risus. Mauris elementum dolor eget ligula pharetra vestibulum. In eu enim eu dui interdum vestibulum.</p>

      <p>Ut quis libero et neque lobortis tempus. Quisque adipiscing eleifend lacus, iaculis adipiscing nibh porttitor ut. Sed dapibus nisl quis mauris sagittis blandit. Donec a tellus non ipsum mollis pretium. Morbi non lectus ut purus porttitor auctor. Praesent vulputate dictum augue nec elementum. Nulla facilisi. Duis auctor, metus molestie egestas pellentesque, sem nulla fringilla risus, a ultrices nunc sem ut eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras id neque volutpat nisl sollicitudin vestibulum auctor quis ligula.</p>

      <p>Sed eget bibendum nisl. Ut nec odio massa, vitae posuere sem. Pellentesque vel urna sit amet sem gravida dignissim id vitae magna. Mauris aliquam, sapien pharetra malesuada bibendum, nisi metus auctor velit, eu egestas felis metus nec tellus. Morbi elementum pellentesque leo, eget facilisis nunc dictum sit amet. Integer cursus venenatis velit, a laoreet mi aliquet ut. Morbi nisi erat, tristique a porta vitae, hendrerit vel neque. Ut ipsum turpis, lobortis quis congue a, sagittis ut nulla. Donec massa sapien, consectetur facilisis lobortis in, aliquam at justo. Duis feugiat lacus sed sapien condimentum sollicitudin laoreet arcu semper. Phasellus sit amet odio at enim tincidunt congue. Ut ac ante eget eros facilisis faucibus non at mauris.</p>

      <p>Vivamus ultrices dui eu nisi tempus semper. Suspendisse consectetur orci non lectus vestibulum dictum. Sed sodales diam vel magna scelerisque quis lobortis ipsum condimentum. Etiam sem orci, bibendum eget sagittis et, ullamcorper at nibh. In sed dignissim dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur vel euismod augue. Integer pulvinar ultrices velit, iaculis tincidunt est scelerisque sed. Integer non vehicula est. Cras pretium viverra augue, in accumsan ante dictum vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In imperdiet pretium tortor, eget vehicula tellus porttitor vel. Praesent erat erat, commodo ac euismod non, tempor sed sem. Fusce non elit nec velit consequat cursus. Phasellus placerat luctus erat, vitae porta sem pulvinar a. Mauris hendrerit neque vitae elit commodo convallis. In ac risus elit, non aliquam tellus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

​And finally the CSS:

```
  #header{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #menu{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffdddd;
  }
  #content{
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
  }
```

Sorry those links don't work for you. Not certain why. Any way you should be able to plop this into a test.html page and see the solution.

Comment: You can't get to jsbin, or the code I put there does not work?

Comment: I can't browse to the url you posted (http://jsbin.com/exevi3/edit).  The jsbin link doesn't work.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsbin.com/exevi3/2/edit This also has an update that include jquery to dynamically keep the heights of your columns set to the height of the window.

Comment: Still no luck.  I can't even browse to www.jsbin.com or jsbin.com for some strange reason.  So, your solution implements jquery to manage the heights?

Comment: I just updated my original comment with the code from jsbin. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, I'll test it out asap and let you know.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I didn't necessarily want to use js for layout purposes BUT, in this case, I can't think of any other way around it.  Your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use tables for this kind of things. Just use divs or proper HTML5.

Secondly, try setting a height on the elements that need a scrollbar. And add this " overflow-y: scroll; "

--> http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: overflow-y: scroll; => only sets a vertical scrollbar

Comment: But I don't know what the height would be.  The page is dynamic and the viewport (screen resolution) is dynamic.  I need to handle both of those situations.

Comment: But this seems like a simple task and I would think it could be done with just CSS.  So, can't think of a layout (even with divs) that will allow me to set the height to 100% and allow overflow?

Comment: No, sorry, can't think of anything :( I always have to use javascript for these kind of things. If your header wouldn't have a fixed height, you MIGHT hack something together. But I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the menu-container to a concrete value (as in px NOT %) to allow it to scroll using: overflow-y: scroll;

Otherwise it doesn't know when to add the scrollbar.

See the simple example @ jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BfWXM/

Comment: The left menu won't be 300px high.  It will be 100%.  And once you change the height to be 100%, the overflow: auto has no affect.